# Running an uwsgi udp server how can be used a python file to handle incoming messages?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I would like to use a uwsgi udp server to receive and handle incoming syslog messages.

```
uwsgi --udp IP_ADDRESS:PORT
```

as it is defined in [uwsgi docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html?highlight=logging#basic-logging-connected-udp-mode)

But I cannot find the way to run a python file/module etc. which can parse and write to database the incoming udp messages.

I've tried

```
uwsgi --udp IP_ADDRESS:PORT --wsgi-file parse.py
```

The parse.py contains an 'application' function but it will be not called (However I can print from the parse.py).

Also tried

```
uwsgi --udp IP_ADDRESS:PORT --python-raw parse.py
```

Again application function will be not called, but I can print from the file.

The uwsgi documentation at this point is very poor.

```
# a very simple parse.py
print('XXX')
def application():
    print('YYY')

output
> XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

uWSGI only supports UDP for caching framework and SNMP. For these applications you don't implement `application(env, start_response)`, but different methods.